# Textarea: can it detect the loss of focus

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML or Javascript is it possible to detect when a textarea looses focus?

I have a text area & on loosing focus I want to read the data in a textarea & check if its valid.

Maybe...

```
<textarea onloosefocus="myFunct();">
</textarea>

// or
var isTyping = false;

function onKeyUp( event )
{
   setTimeout( function()
   {
      isTyping = false;
   }, 100);

   setTimeout( function()
   {
      if (!isTyping)
         validateTextArea();
   }, 500);
}

function onKeyDown( event )
{
   isTyping = true;
}

<textarea onkeydown="onKeyDown(e);" onkeyup="onKeyUp(e);">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 18):

The event you are looking for is the `blur` event, available through the `onblur` attribute:

```
<textarea onblur="myFunct();"></textarea>
```

However, it's much better if you attach events properly, e.g. through jQuery:

```
$('#id_of_your_textarea').on('blur', function(e) {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: How is it "much better", exactly...?

Comment: You don't need to put the function in the global scope for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `onblur` attribute for the textarea if you don't have access to jquery

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery will save you a lot of time, see [.blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)